# ViewPager (Swipe-able tabs) in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, tabs, android-viewpager

I'm trying to build a tabbed bar with swipe-able pages exactly similar to Android's ViewPager. Each page is supposed to hold one UITableView only.
I don't know what's the better way to achieve this but so far I have 2 ideas. Also the tabs are dynamic. I can have one tabs or 10 tabs. It depends on the API I'm communicating with. (The tabs represent shop categories and the table views represent the products)

The tabs will be a UICollectionView and then I'll use one of the following options:

1. First approach is to build two UIViews, each of which will hold a UITableView. One UIView will be outside the screen bounds and the other one will be the one being displayed. When the user swipes and the tabs change, the UIView being displayed will move outside the screen bounds, either to the right or left and the other UIView will be displayed. As soon as the swipe action begins, I will change UIView's (the one that's about to be displayed) datasource and reload its data.
2. Second approach is to have a number of ViewControllers OR UIViewContainers equal to the number of tabs (which is dynamic). I'm not sure how I'd implement this because I'd have to worry about reusing UIViewControllers/UIViewContainers inside of my main UIViewController as well as handling a large number of them.
3. Using one big UICollectionView to host a UITableView in each UICollectionView cell. It's pretty much the reverse of the old App Store.
   [UICollectionView in UITableView Tutorial](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/)

So, how do most people implement similar UIs? Is there a different approach I should consider? Any other tips that can help me implement it?

EDIT: I may have left a final detail. I actually have 2 sets of tabs (categories and sub categories). They may both be displayed, one of them, or none. It depends on the API's response. For that reason, using a 3rd party library may be hard or even impossible.

EDIT2: Added 3rd approach.

[image]

Comment: You can use the component made for iOS, mostly by google engineer itself.
 [material-components-ios](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios)

Comment: @pawan I'm not sure if it would work because I actually have 2 sets of tabs being displayed at the same time. Sometimes both of them will be shown, sometimes only one and sometimes none. (Categories and subcategories).